# Can't create ActiveXComponent using JACOB

Tags: java, com, activex, lync, jacob

since migrating to Lync 2013, my code fails at

```
ActiveXComponent officeCommunicatorActiveX = new ActiveXComponent("Communicator.UIAutomation");
```

with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:101)
```

I tried some online solutions, but none worked.
Lync is running in 32 bit mode, and I ran my app with bot 32 & 64 bit JDKs - didn't matter.
Am i using JACOB wrong ?

EDIT:
before running this code, I choose my JACOB dll with:

```
if (shouldLoad32Bit()) {
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, Files.JACOB_32.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, Files.JACOB_64.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for this API is discontinued in Lync 2013.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/222958e2-24f9-46bf-b79a-eb88a3feac72/lync-2013-client-ocs-2007-automation-api-compatibility?forum=communicatorsdk

Comment: Try to find ProgramID for `Lync 2013` using OLE viewer. Follow Object Classes > All Objects. http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/OLE-COM-Object-Viewer.shtml

Comment: couldn't find one... what exactly am I looking for?